# How to show data from 2 different lists into single view and how to filter items on the basis of defined terms in taxonomy in o365 sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a 2 lists on SharePoint modern environment o365.Where list A contains Questions and their responses and LIST B contains Conversations. I want to create a view or something similar to showcase both list's data collectively. Kindly suggest what approach should I use and how. Below are the problem statements which we want to achieve.

1. Create a single combined view for Questions and Conversations.
2. Implement Search across both lists A&B (questions and conversations).
3. Ability to filter both lists A&B by categories(Categories are defined as a termset in taxonomy) similar to search filters in the Sharepoint classic environment.

Kindly suggest the best ways to achieve the above tasks in SharePoint o365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first requirement, you could create a page, then insert two lists as web parts on the page.

For second and third requirements, I suggest you add the highlighted content web part, then use this web part to search and filter.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd